# Could you please have a notice or other encouragement for new users to take the tour first?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, notification-bar, tour, sign-up

As a new user, enjoying your site, really knowledgeable crowd out here, but I have come to some grief — downvotes, closed question etc.

It would have helped — please consider a strong encouragement to go through the entire tour and help. For example:

> Stack Exchange takes a while to get used to. We are not a forum. To avoid your question being closed, labelled as duplicate, and being temporarily blocked, we encourage you to go through the entire tour and help. We will even give you a badge if you complete the tour.

Comment: I am just going through the tor now for the first time. I had not accepted a lot of answers,  Learning, sorry.

Comment: The banner could use some wordsmithing, but I think the idea is sound and, surprisingly, there's very little indication of the tour's importance upon signing up, nothing much more than a topbar link.