# Make "What's on topic for this site?" visible

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, close-reasons, off-topic

Often, when I want to ask a question (such as now on [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)), I wonder:

*"Is it on topic or not for this specific SE site?*"

then, I'm parsing the page visually, trying to find if there is an info box with a link to a "On topic for this site" page, but I don't find any.

Then, I open another tab, and google "on topic tex stackexchange", and then I find [this `/help/on-topic` link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

As this is not obvious / not super-easy to find, I think that most new people don't search this page, leading to potential off-topic questions, etc.

Question: **Wouldn't there be a place for a (small) link "what's on topic?" in the home page of SE sites?** Or at least for < 1k rep users?

Pros:

- It helps users to know more about the specific SE they are using
- It helps to avoid off-topic / to-be-migrated questions

Something like that in home page:

[image]

and like that in the asking question page:

[image]

*Note: I just used tex.SE as an example, but that could apply to all other SE sites.*

*Note 2: It might be linked to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277607/ways-to-give-users-some-specific-education-about-question-quality-and-topicality) but not a duplicate in the sense that here the proposal is just a small one-line link on home page, which is quite different to [what is suggested here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbw1f.png).*

Comment: Well, it *is* the first link in the [Help Center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, but from the home page, we have to *first* have the idea to go to the Help Center, and *then* parse [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help) to see that the link we're interested in is the in first column, and *then* clicking on this link, i.e. 3 operations. Of course, when you know it, it's obvious. But my point is that, for new users or even not-so-new users (I use SE since years, and I forgot that  the link can be found here, that's why I usually google to find the on topic page), it wouldn't harm to have "on-topic" link more present.

Comment: @Glorfindel It's the top left item in a grid of ~30 links, that isn't necessarily an obvious way to mark it as the most important part of that page. For me, almost all items there look equally important, so if I didn't know it, I might not look at that position first.

Comment: Probably a [related answer in the new navbar thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300857/287976) also (same concern about ton topic at least)

Comment: We're currently keeping a list of things to try in order to improve overall question quality. I'll throw this idea on that list... no idea if it'd work well or, honestly, if we'll try it the way you're describing, but it could be an interesting experiment to run on new users.

Comment: **Related:** When we want to remind users about the *What topics can I ask about here?* page via a comment, `[help/on-topic]` expands to just "help center"; it should expand to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).   See [**this request**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296745/improve-the-link-text-of-the-magic-link-help-on-topic).

Comment: Note the screenshot is displaying the old theme of yonder year when a site's name could be centered and be allowed space to "breathe".Today, much like politics, everything is either on the left or on the right. I wonder if the current lack of symmetry and balance influences users' perception and expectations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can we find a site charter/purpose that tells us the types of question on/off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387354/where-can-we-find-a-site-charter-purpose-that-tells-us-the-types-of-question-on)

Comment: As of March 2023, I think that it's fair to say that what is on topic on this site is **very** visible (see [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387362/289691) to the suggested [duplicate target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387354/where-can-we-find-a-site-charter-purpose-that-tells-us-the-types-of-question-on), if you don't agree, please consider to update this question).

Comment: @Rubén. No it is **not**. When you visit the home page e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/, you have no idea to go to `/help/on-topic` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This link is not present on the home page. Of course, yes, if you already know that `/help/on-topic` exists, then it is visible, but you must know that this page exists in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I added an answer explaining why I think this post should be updated (or at least no longer used as duplicate target).

Comment: @Rubén well it's not a duplicate to begin with, not even close. The question you linked to asks "Where can we find X?", this one asking "Please put X in a better location". Those are very different things on meta sites, each should have its own answer. Related, sure. Duplicate, not at all.

Answer (score 21):

#### This seems like a good use of the <strike>wasted</strike> open space in the left nav bar:

[image]

Since the left nav bar takes up the space anyway – and is prominent enough – it seems to me the perfect place for this kind of thing. The left nav is enabled by default, and even if it is disabled, the link would stay in the menu.

It could be shown only to newish users,  triggered by something like

- reputation
- posts posted
- age of account

Comment: The nav bar is indeed rather underutilized at the moment. In this idea, I'd suggest that the link stay in the sidebar regardless of reputation, because I think the information in that link is helpful for users of all reputations. Also, having the link randomly appear/disappear on you based on which site you're on and how much reputation you have seems like confusing behaviour to me. (See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange) for an example of a site with a helpful collection of links in the sidebar.)

Answer (score 14):

This is an excellent question. It echoes my own annoyance over this aspect of the current user experience at Stack Exchange. In my mind this is also the most "on top" of the "on-topic problem" questions:

- [Discovering on-topic rules of a new SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238105/discovering-on-topic-rules-of-a-new-se-site)
- [Drawing more attention to */help/on-topic on the “Ask Question” page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213935/drawing-more-attention-to-help-on-topic-on-the-ask-question-page)
- [On-topic list is too hard to find in the new help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183213/on-topic-list-is-too-hard-to-find-in-the-new-help-center)
- [Can we get a hotlink for the “On Topic” page in the Help Center?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184817/can-we-get-a-hotlink-for-the-on-topic-page-in-the-help-center)
- [Can we find a way make sure that new users acknowledge the on-topic page before being able to post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290485/can-we-find-a-way-make-sure-that-new-users-acknowledge-the-on-topic-page-before)
- [Insist on “on-topicness” when user enters Ask Question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247621/insist-on-on-topicness-when-user-enters-ask-question-page)
- [Is there a place to get the textual overview (what is on-topic) of all sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203463/is-there-a-place-to-get-the-textual-overview-what-is-on-topic-of-all-sites)
- [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

I agree with the general observation that  `help/on-topic` is too hard to find - "buried" in such a counterintuitive manner that new users, or in my case, returning forgetful users, tend to conclude that it doesn't even exist. We conclude this because:

- The home page has links to *unimportant* information like "Users" and "Badges" front and center, links that I never click on. This makes it seem that *important* information, like what's on-topic - something which everyone has to know, and which can be very [non-obvious for certain sites](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - does not actually have a page of its own. Users conclude that this information is meant to be guessed at by e.g. perusing the "Top Questions" list which is displayed so prominently.
- The "Help Center" link is tiny and hidden compared to the other links on the home page. The Help Center contains a table of links to information which is the same for each site, like "Code of Conduct" and "What does it mean if a question is 'closed' or 'on hold'?". Much of it is common-sense even to first time Stack Exchange users. The very name "Help Center", and the fact that seemingly all but one of the questions in the table is generic in nature, communicates to users that this is not the place to find out about non-obvious site-specific information.
- The "Tour" has a promising name, but it's also buried, and when you click on it you see that it is generic and animated, lacking site-specific information.

I agree with the various proposals for making the `help/on-topic` page more visible from the Help Center, from the "Ask Question" page, and so on. However, in my own experience, I expect to find this information very easily from the home page itself - before I even decide to ask a question, and before I classify myself as someone who needs "help".

To answer the OP's embedded question, "Wouldn't there be a place for a (small) link "what's on topic?" in the home page of SE sites?", the answer is yes. A link to `help/on-topic` would be more useful than most of the other stuff in the headers of SE sites, so there is certainly room for it in the UI, not just a small link but a big one.

I was going to suggest adding an "About" link to the right of the site logo, and to the left of the existing links "Questions", "Tags", "Users", "Badges", "Unanswered", and "Ask Question". Then I saw that a new UI is being rolled out, see for example [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/), and I was forced to reconsider my proposal. In retrospect I like my new proposal much better:

### Clicking on the site logo should take you to `help/on-topic`.

- The most important distinguishing information about each site is in the `help/on-topic` page, titled "What topics can I ask about here?". The logo is what distinguishes each site visually. Thus, it is natural that clicking on the logo would take users to `help/on-topic`.
- The logo is also the most "visible" part of the home page. So this proposal would solve, at least in a certain sense, the identified need of making `help/on-topic` more "visible".
- Currently, clicking on an SE site logo doesn't do anything but redisplay the home page with the "Top Questions" list. I would be OK with keeping this behavior on question pages, but on the home page the behavior is useless since it just redisplays what the user is already looking at.
- When I have gone months without using SE, and then I create an account on a new site, I often click on the site logo thinking it will tell me something important about the site. So based on my own intuition as a web user, I think that other people, both new and old users, will be able to discover on their own that clicking on a site logo leads to information about the site.

That's my proposal.

Comment: The logo goes to the front page, which contains Q&A.  A list of questions is the logical "main" page for a site.  Appropriating the logo for help for new users, at the cost of usability for existing users (some with close to a decade of muscle memory), is a bad trade.  It also still relies on new users stumbling into it.  Far better to use actual words to point the way, and/or use (dismissable) "heroes" to tell new users about a site's scope.

Comment: Reasonable points, but not sure if you read the third bullet under the proposal.

Comment: I'm responding to "Clicking on the site logo should take you to help/on-topic" (in bold).

Comment: Yes, and I was referring you to the third bullet down from that text: "Currently, ..."

Comment: This answer makes a good job addressing the underlying problem (I started a bounty in including a link to it). I think that it might require to include links to some latest posts. By the other hand, I don't think that the proposed change (clicking on the site logo should point to /help/on-topic) will solve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

So I was browsing Super User, and I thought, 'say, what exactly *is* on-topic for this site anyway?' And even though I've been on Stack Overflow for years, and I'm pretty familiar with how these sites work, it took me a considerable amount of time for me to find this information:

1. Okay, from front page, go to Ask Question:

   [image: SU front page]
2. From "Ask a question", go to "asking help":

   [image: SU ask a question]
3. From "How do I ask a good question?", go to "What topics can I ask about here?":

   [image: SU how to ask]
4. Finally! This is what I was looking for!

   [image: SU on-topic]

All that seems a bit unnecessarily long-winded and difficult. Knowing if a question is on-topic or not is one of the most important things that a new user could know before asking their question, yet this information is so difficult to find...

- The `(?)` > `Help center` > `What topics can I ask about here?` route involves clicking on a menu button to reveal hidden menu options, so I think this route is less obvious.
- There's also the `New Tab` > `Google: "Super User on-topic"` > `What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center - Super User` route, but a user shouldn't really have to go off-site to find something as fundamental as *what is accepted on a site*. Additionally, this route requires additional [mental preparation and keystrokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke-level_model), which also makes it take longer.

I'd argue that a fundamental problem that all Stack Exchange sites are suffering from is that at the moment, "on-topic" requires **recall, not recognition**. It should be the other way around. User interface designs should promote [recognition over recall](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/recognition-and-recall/):

> One of the top 10 usability heuristics advises to promote recognition over recall in user-interface design. Showing users things they can recognize improves usability over needing to recall items from scratch because the extra context helps users retrieve information from memory.

To Google "Super User on-topic", you have to *recall* that these sites *have* on-topic criteria. To go down that [obfuscated long-winded route](https://youtu.be/m8OQkD40ly0?t=153) to get to the "What topics can I ask about here?" page, you have to *recall* the route to get to that page.

If you don't happen to already know how to get to that page, then (as previously pointed out in comments by [Basj](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301363/make-whats-on-topic-of-this-site-visible#comment979805_301363) and [Mad Scientist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301363/make-whats-on-topic-of-this-site-visible#comment979808_301363)) the unnecessarily high number of operations required to get to that page would prevent users (especially new users) from reading or even being aware of the page in the first place. *We want users to read this page!*

---

**My suggestion:** Change the "How to Ask" box on the "Ask a question" page to link directly to the on-topic page. Users see this box right before they start typing their question, so by the ["Just In Time" theory of user behaviour](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-just-in-time-theory/), putting the information here should have the highest visibility.

As an example, here's a starting point for how the Stack Overflow "How to Ask" box could look:

[image: example improved how to ask box]

Several points:

1. The first line **directly links to** the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

   - This should really be the first thing that users see upon arriving on this page.
   - Also, Stack Overflow has a new user to read through a version of the "How to Ask" guide and requires them to tick a checkbox that they've read everything before they can access the "Ask a question" page. But once they get here, there's no obvious way to get back to that information page to reread it or reference it in case they're unsure about something. This would fix that.
2. The first line is a **direct call to action** to read the "how to ask" guide.

   - Users will skim over things like passive questions or unassuming links tucked away in the bottom, but direct calls to action will draw their attention.
3. The second line **directly links** to the [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

   - I think any internet-savvy person knows how [topic hyperlinking works](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MOS:EGG), so if the user is at any point unsure about if their topic counts as "related to programming", the hyperlink is at right their fingertips to check.
   - *There's a huge difference between this and what is currently in place*. At the moment, the "on-topic" page is buried behind several pages of links. It's completely unfair to expect new users to know where to find it or that it exists in the first place. If this page is shown to users more prominently, more users will click on it and actually read it.
4. The second line uses **requirement language**.

   - Questions **must** meet these requirements. Phrasing it as a question or using language like "we prefer" makes it seem like these are only suggestions, which is not the impression that we want to give. Using direct language like this gets the point across more clearly.
5. Users see that this information is available **every time they ask a question**, and continually **as they're composing their question**.

   - Because forgetting curve.

   [image: forgetting curve]

Other ideas:

- Ability for sites to add custom messages to their "How to Ask" box to address common misconceptions about the site scope.

  - For example, [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions) stopped accepting identification request questions a while ago, but we still see a steady flow of such questions. To be fair to the new users, that "How to Ask" box is really misleading. All of the questions that are being closed are indeed "about anime or manga" and they "can be answered, not just discussed". I feel like adding a single line of text to that box to preemptively clarify this would really save both moderators and new users a lot of grief.
  - [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions) still receives a fair amount of personal medical advice questions. I think it'd help a lot if there was a line in the "How to Ask" box that clarifies what exactly counts as personal medical advice and what doesn't, so that more users would be aware of this before asking a question.

---

From my reading of other similar discussions, I see people tend to say things like "users are lazy and they won't read instructions, what good will this do?" and "I don't think this will do any good". But the process for checking what's on-topic for a site is unnecessarily long and obfuscated *even for an experienced user of these sites*. I think any improvement along these lines would be a good thing.

Comment: Nowadays to customize the Ask Question form the process requires to post a [meta-tag:feature-request] in the corresponding per-site meta. Ref. [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691) from March, 2020.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a similar feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387485/slogan-motto-credo-goal-summary-of-site-next-to-logo) but [this comment](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14934/slogan-motto-credo-goal-summary-of-site-next-to-logo?noredirect=1#comment43898_14934) claims it should've been in the form of a question, so i'll use this answer as an alternative to the suggested link in the yellow box on the right: A short summary in the blank space at the top:
[image: CLEAR SITE SUMMARY instead of guide/tour/howto/docs link]
To avoid [doubts](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14934/slogan-motto-credo-goal-summary-of-site-next-to-logo?noredirect=1#comment43897_14934) about the new text, using the existing question title placeholder text or even the summary shown when clicking on a site at https://stackexchange.com/sites might help.

Comment: As the author of the target of the link with text "doubts" I was referring to the proposed text as  Super User "motto": "Personal computer questions only!" (which is shown in the image). Anyway, this request is obsolete as several changes were already made to the homepage and the Ask Question form. In [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387362/289691) to [Where can we find a site charter/purpose that tells us the types of question on/off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387354/289691) I have added multiple snapshots taken recently of the places where the site purpose is shown.

Comment: The idea proposed here looks to imply a change in the site theme. Nowadays to customize it the process requires to post a [meta-tag:feature-request] in the corresponding per-site meta. Ref. [Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/289691) from December, 2018.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that this feature request should be updated and improved.

It should be updated due to the changes launched after it was posted:

- [Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/289691) from December, 2018
- [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691) from March, 2020

More specifically, nowadays to customize the *site theme* (design) and *Ask Question form* the process requires to post a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) in the corresponding per-site meta.

It might require a discussion on per-site metas about why the use of `Help` as link text, the help button and the `Tour` as link text aren't effective to quicly find the `../help/on-topic`. Also on the per-site meta might discuss why "Help Center" might not mean anything for users of that specific community.

By the other hand, this feature request might require more work explaining why modifing the homepage *for all the Stack Exchange sites* will work better than the currents elements in the homepage like the help button, the banner shown to anonymous users, the Tour link in site footer. Also it should consider this initiative:  [Introducing new user onboarding project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364572/289691) from 2021,

It also requires more focus. I think that the discussion about the Ask Question form should be removed as at this time the Staging Ground initiative is on going and it goes hand to hand with the new Ask Wizard. See [How might the Staging Ground & the new Ask Wizard work on the Stack Exchange network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377768/289691).

P.S.

1. Few days ago I posted an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387362/289691) to [Where can we find a site charter/purpose that tells us the types of question on/off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387354/289691) including a screenshot of several elements that show links to `../help/on-topic`
2. This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314761/289691) deserve to stand over as it points the underlying problem.

Related [feature-requests](/questions/tagged/feature-requests)

- [Could the intro banner not be displayed if already displayed in one tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85407/289691)
- [Could you please have a notice or other encouragement for new users to take the tour first?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287598/289691)

Related

- [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/289691)
- [Create a guided tour for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126009/289691)
- [Introducing a brand new, consolidated, Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182812/289691)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377059/289691
  Includes a semi-manually updated liste of all the sites that have customized the Ask Question Step 1: Draft your question box.
- [Which sites have customized their help center homepage?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386786/289691)

Answer (score -4):

There's already a link in the question screen to how to ask:

[image: Ask question screenshot]

This page link to on-topic as part of other recommendations :

[image: How to ask page screenshot]

For users under 500 reputation, the new navbar also include a question mark with links to the tour and help center:

[image: New navbar screenshot]

This is already ignored so much I don't see how linking the on topic page again elsewhere would really help.
My point is, there's already multiple question ignoring search (duplicates), be on topic (this is the subject), be specific (how much too broad questions?) and make it relevant to others (too localized is not a close reason anymore but the idea still stand) everyday even if that's just a link away to see it.

Either you're willing to know what is on-topic and you'll have a look at the correct pages *and* site's meta or you just want to ask your question without more consideration (most cases) and another link won't help much.

There's no harm adding it, but I've still to be convinced this would improve question on-topicness and reduce migrations.

Comment: Top down: "asking help" in blue....

Comment: We could very well add a link on top of this sentence: `Our community is defined by a specific [set of topics](**LINK HERE**), please stick to those topics and avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion.`. Adding such a link would be easy and would even not require to add a sentence and/or to find a new place in UI for it, because it's already there!

Comment: Just a second, I'll add two screenshots

Comment: My point is: instead of `=> click on "that you can view in the help center" => find the link for on-topic page => click on the link`  we could do: `=> click on "specific set of topics"` done!

Comment: *"This is already ignored so much I don't see how linking it again elsewhere would really help"*: my point is: it is ignored because it requires to do several operations => going to help => finding the on-topic link => clicking on it => ... That's why a direct link could help.

Comment: @Basj answer updated, I'm still not convinced people ignoring the basis of question formatting and not even hovering on the editor button would click anywhere to assess their question are on topic. I, personally, would close as "Won't fix" if it was an issue.

Comment: @Basj you're proving the point yourself, you didn't even bother clicking on the "asking help" link to write a paragraph on how it doesn't fulfill the goal actually and did ask for a screenshot to spot it, do you really think another link on a sentence would be more noticed ?

Comment: No I didn't ask screenshot for this. I asked screenshot because I thought you were speaking about another place (that I might not have known). Sometimes layout changes, as I'm often reading SO / SE on mobile or tablet or desktop, I am used to see different layouts etc. I just wanted to be sure we spoke about the same thing. It's not about not bothering, it's really the contrary of this...

Comment: @Basj I've added a paragraph to explain a little more why I don't think one more link would help anyway, there's 4 points in the [ask] page which are just a link away and are ignored, so adding one more link doesn't sound like a solution to me. (This is to answer your "too much operations", just the points on the how to ask page are already skipped, so putting on-topic one link away instead of two won't make a big change  IMHO)

Comment: To me, "asking help" sounds like formatting or process, not scope.  (I don't think I've ever clicked on it.)  And while experienced users know that help includes the page about what's on-topic, it doesn't seem to be very obvious to new users.  First-time visitors get an invitation to take the tour, so there's that at least, but it's a one-shot.

Comment: @MonicaCellio fair point

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I'd forgotten that "asking help" links to /help/on-topic, actually, which suggests it's ... not especially intuitive.